# Where is the PCV valve on my 2011 Ford Focus SES (Duratec engine)?

Tags: scheduled-maintenance, pcv-valve

I have a 2011 Ford Focus SES with a 2.0 liter I4 Duratec PZEV (California edition) engine.

My repair manual suggests replacing the PCV valve every 60k miles (I am currently at 75k). I am trying to find the PCV valve but am not sure where it is.

YouTube videos suggest it should be at the top driver's side, but the Hanes repair manual says I'll need to remove the intake manifold to access it. The Hanes repair manual is also not terribly accurate for the 2011 model year. It contains no information about the Duratec engines.

Before I go through all that effort to find it, I'd like to know if anyone knows for sure where it is, and if it even is really necessary to replace at the moment.

Here is a link to a couple photos of my engine compartment.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuBKK.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Haynes manual is correct you need to remove the intake to access the PCV valve.

The hose from the valve cover to the intake tube is a breather hose.

The valve in question.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Crap. I am not looking forward to that at all. Where did you find that diagram? And do you think it's necessary to replace the valve?

Comment: @JeremyWhite It's a cropped exploded diagram Ford provides, I got it off a subscription site. I'd stick to the maintenance schedule for the part. If it's only suggested wait until they say it's required to replace it unless a drivability concern occurs. But to be honest most car's go their lifetime without replacing a PCV valve.